# Fresh install on a new M2 ssd going in read only mode the fist day!

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, fsck, read-only

I did fresh install of latest Ubuntu on a new lapotop with M2 ssd.

The first day after I have had left an app to build it's database I found it switched to read only mode.

I used whole disk encryption AND home dir encryption during the install.

reboot and fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root fixes the situation. 
It finds quite a bit of errors but fixes them all and all is fine until it happens again.

Used to do the same trick before, hence the fresh reinstall. Because I thought I might have messed up something on the old one.

I did full hardware check from the bios, all is fine.

Looks to me like for some reason Ubuntu messes up something when full disk encryption AND home dir encryption are used on the latest 17.04
was just fine with the previous version. Used it like that for years with not even a single problem!

Comment: Check the manufacturer's web site for a firmware update for the M2 SSD.

Comment: It's the samsung nvme ssd but I can't find much about updating it's firmware. 

Do you think it might be something else?

Comment: See http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html